# Getting arrows above plotted lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot:

[image]

I simply would like the red arrows / lines to show up **above** the blue lines. Right now it looks like they're getting swallowed up by the blue. Is there a command / argument I can add to make this happen?

EDIT: My code right now looks something like this:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

```
yellow_line = B0_prob_m

n = 1000

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[10,10])

binaries = [np.random.randint(2, size=(80,80)) for k in range(255)]
blue_lines = ['n lists of length 255 to make the blue lines']

for k in range(n):
    blue_line_k = blue_lines[k]
    ax.plot(blue_line_k, 'b', alpha=0.2)

ax.plot(yellow_line, 'y', linewidth=5.0)

chosen_Ks = [70, 105, 112, 145]
x = 25
for k in chosen_Ks:
    binary = binaries[k]
    imagebox = OffsetImage(binary, zoom=1, cmap='gray')
    ab = AnnotationBbox(imagebox, (x,100), frameon = True)
    ax.add_artist(ab)
    plt.arrow(x, 100, k-x, -100+B0_prob_m[k],color='r')

    x += 75

ax.set_title('Beta0')
```

Comment: Possibly `zorder`, but please create a [reprex].

Comment: @BigBen thanks! zorder worked. I'm actually surprised I didn't know about it before and it didn't show up on my searches.